# Squid Proxy only able to go to Google

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I recently reconfigured my Squids to only except traffic requests from a local subnet. When I did that I keep running into issues when one of my servers tries to access a website through the squid proxy it gets a refusal. Strangely I can access google and run searches but I am unable to go anywhere else. The servers and squid servers are all in the 10.0.0.0 subnet. What in my conf is causing this?

My conf setup is as follows.

```
http_port 3128
cache deny all
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?

access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache_log /dev/null

refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0% 0
refresh_pattern . 0 20% 4320

acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl localnet localnet10 10.0.0.0/24 
acl localnet localnet192 192.168.0.0/16

acl SSL_ports port 1-65535
acl Safe_ports port 1-65535
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl siteblacklist dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist.acl"
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access deny siteblacklist
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid3/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd

auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
#acl password proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet10
http_access allow localnet192

#http_access allow password

acl client src WHITE_LISTED_IP_ADDR
http_access allow client

# http_access allow all
http_access deny all

forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all
```

Comment: What's inside WHITE_LISTED_IP_ADDR?

Comment: currently its empty.